# Why does the wifi button of my LTS operating system not work?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I just installed Ubuntu LTS 16 on my Dell laptop.
Cable network works, but the wifi button does not.
There's no wifi button, no wifi retriever... no nothing.

I tried with restarting and reinstalling but nothing changed.

I think that the wifi technology is not active, maybe.

Here's the output of my device check.

Any idea?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 17 Dec 2016 00:38 EST -0500

Booted last: 17 Dec 2016 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1673] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [1028:01f9]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1490 Dual Band WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 0b97:7772 O2 Micro, Inc. OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

PRODID_1=""
PRODID_2=""
PRODID_3=""
PRODID_4=""
MANFID=0000,0000
FUNCID=255

##### rfkill ############################

0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6365184  1
dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_laptop            20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
cfg80211              565248  1 wl
wmi                    20480  1 dell_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp9s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.2.133  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::efd:f9ac:bd92:57a5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10269 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10726306 (10.7 MB)  TX bytes:946140 (946.1 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp9s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp9s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp9s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp9s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       687     1  0 00:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp9s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tg3
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.137
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               5755m-v3.29
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp9s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:09:00.0/net/enp9s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp9s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       0c64eb3e-6174-3ab3-9f0f-16ce009bfef8
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   0c64eb3e-6174-3ab3-9f0f-16ce009bfef8 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.2.133/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.2.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.2.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1482212125
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.2.133
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.2.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 259200
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.2.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.2.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::efd:f9ac:bd92:57a5/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Toronto (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp9s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp9s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     4DDC5FCDB1E30F7DFDCA530
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     00D8DA6D3B739DDD31FFF50
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############

Download as text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have the wrong driver installed for your wireless. With a reliable internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot.

Comment: Perfect, now it works!